# Multi-line numpy where() condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Folks,
To avoid a for loop, I am working on a vector-based way of doing the following:

Array_1 has float values ranging from -3.0 to 3.0 and walks randomly between these extremes.

I want to create Array_2 to be something like this:

```
Array_2 = np.where((Array_1[row] > 2) & (Array_1[row-1] < 2),1,0)
```

HOW can I accomplish this within my np.where() condition?
Ultimately I want to avoid a for-loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think an input/output example would help for clarity ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), you apply [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) on the input to construct a helper array that will let you access the original array with an offset

```
>>> x = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, 20)
array([ 0.87457789,  2.78372382,  2.99091498,  1.13015817,  2.08503683,
        1.48561846, -1.30544443, -1.34806256,  0.46013052,  1.71623744,
       -1.11043827, -0.14515713,  2.81997195,  0.62134152, -1.95262578,
       -0.93686073,  0.56367685,  1.96501996,  0.59958956,  2.6594141 ])
```

Roll `x` with an offset of `1`:

```
>>> (x > 2)*(np.roll(x, 1) < 2)
array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, 
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, 
       False, False, False, False, False,  True])
```

If you want to coerce the resulting array to integers or floating points:

```
>>> (x > 2)*(np.roll(x, 1) < 2)*1
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: That does the trick! Thanks!Funny, I always use "helper columns" in Excel but the the idea didn´t occur to me this time!

Comment: keep in mind that `roll` rolls the last item to the first place, this might cause unexpected edge cases is the first and last items form a matching condition ;)

Comment: Yes! roll did not work because of that, however, it gave me an idea: as I am working with Pandas actually, used `.shift` to create the helped column. It then went into another error: `Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.` , I have encompassed the whole clause with an `np.array(clause, dtype=object)` but it is still not working!!!

Comment: @rpin Can you tell us what your edge case is?

Comment: @Ivan, if you mean more detail on the situation, I am trying to refactor a code built with a lot of for-loops into a vector-based code for speed of processing a large data set. Data is time-series and I want to do something "today" IF something happened "yesterday" (row-1) on the data. Basically that's it.

Comment: @rpin No, you said *"roll did not work because of that"*, what I meant by edge case is how do you want to handle the edge case on the index `0`. In other words, your definition does not define `Array_2[0]` since, then `Array_1[row-1] = Array_1[-1]` which scorresponds to the last element of `Array_1`.

Comment: Ah ok. I have used pd.shift(1). Ignored index 0 but that won’t be a problem because for row 0 I will treat separately and compare that row with a helper variable. What did not work is roll() makes index[-1] be index 0 in the rolled column. That did not help so changed to shift.